# Shared object and resource file with company name?

Tags: android, linux, embedded-resource, elf, shared-objects

I'm  working on an Android phone issue. I can't find a mod for my HTC EVO 4G (Kingdom). Apparently, a company called [DxO Labs used DMCA to force Cyanogenmod to remove some HTC mods](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/03/13/dxo-labs-issues-dmca-takedown-requests-on-12-github-repositories-some-cyanogenmod-repos-affected/).

I want to get a list of shared objects built by DxO Labs on the EVO. I have the device so I can enumerate all the shared objects on the device. What I don't know is if ELF DSOs are built with (or could be built with) company information like Windows executables. I don't ever recall coming across them, but I don't believe I ever looked.

Do Linux executables and shared objects in ELF format have a mechanism similar to Windows resource files? Sorry to have to ask. I'm having trouble locating a document on Android's ELF File format and ABI like other platforms have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [SYSTEM V APPLICATION BINARY INTERFACE](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf), it is possible to mark objects with company information. From page 81, *Notes* section:

> Sometimes a vendor or system builder needs to mark an object file with
>   special information that other programs will check for conformance,
>   compatibility, etc. Sections of type `SHT_NOTE` and program header
>   elements of type `PT_NOTE` can be used for this purpose. The note
>   information in sections and program header elements holds any number
>   of entries, each of which is an array of 4-byte words in the format of
>   the target processor. Labels appear below to help explain note
>   information organization, but they are not part of the specification.
>
> ```
> +----------------+
> |     namesz     |
> +----------------+
> |      descz     |
> +----------------+
> |      type      |
> +----------------+
> |      name      |
> +----------------+
> |      desc      |
> +----------------+
> ```
>
> **`namesz` and `name`**: The first `namesz` bytes in `name` contain a null-terminated character representation of the entry’s owner or
>   originator. There is no formal mechanism for avoiding name conflicts.
>   By convention, vendors use their own name, such as ‘‘XYZ Computer
>   Company,’’ as the identifier. If no name is present, `namesz` contains
>   0. Padding is present, if necessary, to ensure 4-byte alignment for the
>   descriptor. Such padding is not included in `namesz`.
>
> **`descsz` and `desc`**: The first `descsz` bytes in `desc` hold the note descriptor. The ABI places no constraints on a descriptor’s
>   contents. If no descriptor is present, `descsz` contains 0. Padding is
>   present, if necessary, to ensure 4-byte alignment for the next note
>   entry. Such padding is not included in `descsz`.
>
> **`type`**: This word gives the interpretation of the descriptor. Each originator controls its own types; multiple interpretations of a
>   single type value may exist. Thus, a program must recognize both the
>   name and the type to ‘‘understand’’ a descriptor. Types currently must
>   be nonnegative. The ABI does not define what descriptors mean.

And from page 115 on  Vendor Extensions:

> Besides the services listed above, libc may contain other symbols. An
>   ABI-conforming system vendor may add a symbol to the C library to
>   provide vendor-specific services. The ABI does not define these
>   services, and programs using these services are not ABI-conforming.
>   Nonetheless, the ABI defines a recommended extension mechanism,
>   providing a way to avoid conflict among the services from multiple
>   vendors.
>
> A symbol of the form `_$vendor.company`. company provides an
>   operating system entry for the vendor named company. The C library
>   does not have unadorned alternatives for these names. Conventionally,
>   a vendor uses the single name to provide multiple services, letting
>   the first argument to `_$vendor.company` select among the
>   alternatives. As an example, the ‘‘XYZ Computer Company’’ might add
>   `_$vendor.xyz` to the C library.